# PHP __autoload() from lower directory

Tags: php, class, subdomain

I a primary website and a site using a subdomain with the following directory structure

Primary website:

```
/home/mysite/public_html/
```

Subdomain:

```
/home/mysite/subdomain/
```

I would like my classes directory to be shared between the primary and subdomain. The classes reside here:

```
/home/mysite/public_html/classes/
```

I am trying to autoload the classes from a file in the subdomain's directory

```
/home/mysite/subdomain/includes/bootstrap.php
```

which contains this code:

```
$classdir = '/home/mysite/public_html/classes/';

function __autoload($class_name) {
    var_dump($class_name);
    require_once ($classdir.$class_name.'.php');
}
```

My issue is that the classes are not being loaded.

Please note this code works perfectly when used in a file located in the primary domain directory:

```
/home/mysite/public_html/includes/bootstrap.php
```

Including them individually works fine, such as:

```
require_once($classdir.'/class1.php');
require_once($classdir.'/class2.php');
```

However there are dozens of them and i would like to autoload them

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue with spl_autoload_register() as below

```
$classdir = '/home/mysite/public_html/classes/';

function autoLoader( $class_name ){
    $path = $classdir . $class_name . '.php';
    include_once( $path );
}

spl_autoload_register( 'autoLoader' );
```